# Sharepoint Workflow question

Tags: workflow

I have a pretty advanced workflow to design.  I have to change permissions on items according to status (I believe I have that figured out via impersonation and if-else blocks.)

However the user would like only certain sharepoint groups to be able to advance the document to the next "stage" in the process.
For instance user a submits doc.
it moves to Created Status
User B looks it over and decides they want to move it to the next status of Review.

However User B can only move it to next level Initial QAPI review. (and not any of the levels beyond that).
then User C can edit and move from QAPI review to supervisor or they can demote it back to Initial QAPI review if they don't like something.

Catch my drift?  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Sharepoint Designer with me right now, so I might forget something. Nevertheless this is how I would approach it:
Create a different content type for every user group. Default content type shall be user A's. Each content type has it's own status column with only two choices. Additionally you create a generic status column, which will be shown in the view (with the other status columns hidden).

Now in your workflow you check for the content type of the current item and create a new item of the following content type. Copy all columns. After that delete the current item of the current content type and notify the next item about the next user group.

I hope this helps a bit.